# How can i change the size of images with multer with sharp?

Tags: node.js, multer

I built a web app and want to resize my images to be smaller for better quality to my profile pictures. I am using "multer" for upload picture and sharp package for resizing.

For some reason i get this error:

```
"[0] [Error: D:\DevConnectors\public\resized\5f4f4e0bb295ba36042536bf.jpg: unable to open for write
[0] windows error: The storage control block address is invalid."
```

My code:

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, DIR)
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    var typeFile = file.originalname.split(".").pop()
    const fileName = req.user.id + "." + typeFile
    cb(null, fileName)
  },
})

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (
      file.mimetype == "image/png" ||
      file.mimetype == "image/jpg" ||
      file.mimetype == "image/jpeg"
    ) {
      cb(null, true)
    } else {
      return cb(new Error("Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!"), false)
    }
  },
})

const Profile = require("../../moduls/Profile")
const User = require("../../moduls/User")

//@route GET/api/profile/me
//@desc Get current users profile
//@access Private

router.post(
  "/upload",
  [auth, upload.single("imageProfile")],
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      console.log(req.file)
      const { filename: image } = req.file
      await sharp(req.file.path)
        .resize(150)
        .jpeg({ quality: 50 })
        .toFile(path.resolve(req.file.destination, "resized", image))

      fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path)

      const url = req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host")
      let user = await User.findById(req.user.id)
      const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
      //Update
      if (user) {
        user.avatar = url + "/public/" + req.file.filename
        await user.save()
        return res.json(profile)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
)
```

This happens at this line :

```
path.resolve(req.file.destination,'resized',image))
```

What am i doing wrong? i am using sharp docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
**Configuration of multer** ( change it according to your needs)

```
import multer from "multer";
import sharpe from "sharp";

const upload = multer({      //multer configuration
  //dest: "avatars",       //so that buffer is available in route handler
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1000000,
  },
  fileFilter(req, file, cb) {        // object method shorthand syntax
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) { //.match for using regex b/w (//)
      return cb(new Error("Please upload a IMAGE"));
    }
    cb(undefined, true);
  },
});
```

handle sharp in your route handle like this.

```
router.post(
           "path",
          upload.single("avatar"),
       async (req, res) => {      
       const buffer = await sharpe(req.file.buffer)
            .png()
            .resize({
              width: 300,
              height: 300
            })
            .toBuffer();
          req.user.avatar = buffer;
          await req.user.save();
          res.send();
        },
        (error, req, res, next) => {
          //to tell express this how mutler/s error should be handled
          res.status(400).send({
            error: error.message,
          });
        }
    );
```

Comment: what about storage? in my multer i save the files in public dir, how can i configure my files to be saved at public dir?

Comment: just add "dest" property and path of your directory where you want to store the files  to multer configuration .
`const upload = multer({
dest: 'path/to/directory'
})`. 


if this answer helped you anyway accept it so that it may help others in the future :)

Comment: @JatinMehrotra req.file.buffer is undefined(no buffer at all) and req.file.path say (input file is missing)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in my case the issue was that the directory (in your case "resized") didn't exist yet. So either create it manually or programmatically like this:

```js
const targetPath = path.resolve(req.file.destination, 'resized')
if (!existsSync(targetPath)) {
  mkdirSync(targetPath);
}
await sharp(...)
```